# Closed form expression for constants

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, power-series, generating-functions

We have the constants $c_{k,n}$ defined by :
$$c_{k,n}=\frac{d^{k}}{ds^{k}}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}}e^{\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s} \right )}}{s} \right ),$$
where $\psi(s)\;$ is [the Digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)  and the derivatives are evaluated at $s=\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. We wish to have a closed-form expression for these constants. I tried [Mellin's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinsFormula.html), but couldn't get answers!

Comment: this is what i tried : using the definition of the digamma :$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m(ms-1)}=-\gamma-\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right)$$. where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, we can write Laurent expansions around each $\frac{1}{n}$: $$\digamma\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right)=-\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k,n}\left(s-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}$$. making use of the identity:
$$\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\frac{(s-s_{0})^{n}}{n!}\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{m}\left(a_{1},...,a_{m}\right)}{m!}(s-s_{0})^{m}$$

Comment: Where $B_{m}\left(a_{1},...,a_{m}\right)$ are the complete Bell polynomials, it becomes fairly easy to compute $c_{k,n}$. However, i couldn't give a formula for the numbers $a_{k,n}$ !!

Comment: sorry, it is : $$\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right) = -\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k,n}\left(s-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}$$

Comment: Don't we always have that $\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}$ term in there regardless of $k$?  So evaluation at $s=1/n$ should give us a $0$ denominator.  What am I missing?

Comment: yeah, but we are evaluating $\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right)+\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}$ and its derivatives. the poles of the digamma term at each $\frac{1}{n}$ cancel with those of $\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}$

Answer (score 2):

by [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) (Higher product rule):

$$\frac{d^k}{ds^k}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}}e^{\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s} \right)}}{s}\right)=$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^k\left(\binom{k}{i}\left(\frac{d^i}{ds^i}e^{\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}}\right)\sum_{j=0}^{k-i}\binom{k-i}{j}\left(\frac{d^j}{ds^j}e^{\psi\left(\frac{s-1)}{s}\right)}\right)(i+j-k)_{-i-j+k}\ s^{i+j-k-1}\right)$$

$(a)_b$: Pochhammer symbol

$$$$

by [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) (Higher chain rule):
$\frac{d^i}{ds^i}e^{f(s)}=e^{f(s)}B_i(f(s))$
$B_i()$ is the [complete exponential Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).
$B_i(f(s))=B_i(f^{(1)}(s),f^{(2)}(s),...,f^{(i)}(s))$

$$\frac{d^i}{ds^i}e^{\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}}=e^{\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}}B_i\left(\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}\right)$$

$$\frac{d^l}{ds^l}\frac{1}{n(ns-1)}=\frac{(-l)_l\ n^l}{n(ns-1)^{l+1}}$$

$$$$

$$\frac{d^j}{ds^j}e^{\psi\left(\frac{s-1)}{s}\right)}=e^{\psi\left(\frac{s-1)}{s}\right)}B_j\left(\psi\left(\frac{s-1)}{s}\right)\right)$$

$$\frac{d^l}{ds^l}\psi\left(\frac{s-1)}{s}\right)=\sum_{t=0}^{2l}(-1)^t\binom{l-1}{t}\binom{l}{t}t!\ \frac{\psi\left(l-t,\frac{s-1}{s}\right)}{s^{2l-t}}$$

$\psi$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). The coefficients of $\frac{\psi\left(l-t,\frac{s-1}{s}\right)}{s^{2l-t}}$ build the series [OEIS: A111884](https://oeis.org/A111884).

Maybe it's possible to derive a formula for the coefficients of the original series on the top.

For $s=\frac{1}{n}$, the series doesn't converge. We have to determine the limit of the series therefore.